# MC34063 issue. Switches off every cycle

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator, mc34063

I am using MC34063 in step down configuration but the converter switches off every cycle. Following are the calculations and specifications:
Vin - 9 to 12V
Vout - 5V
Imax - 0.3A
Rsc - 0.36 ohms
L - 47uH 1.6A
Ct - 270pf
I have tried reducing the current limit resistor value (Rsc), but it didn't help. The usable current is below the designed rated current. I have attached an oscilloscope image showing the output voltage ripple on channel-1 and switching transistor emitter (pin-2 of MC34063A) voltage on channel-2.
Note that the transistor switches off completely causing a low frequency ripple in the output voltage which is unnecessary. Kindly help.
[image: output voltage ripple on channel-1 and switching transistor emitter (pin-2 of MC34063A) voltage on channel-2]
[image: Parameter and component calculations]
[image: Actual PCB layout]

Comment: Its possible that you didnt correctly choose the feedback resistors. What values did you choose?

Comment: please show circuit

Comment: @Golaž The feedback resistors values are correct since I am getting DC output as 5V, but the OFF period and AC ripple is my concern

Comment: @markrages Added the circuit and its calculations

Comment: what are you powering the circuit with?  please add a photograph of the circuit that you built.

Comment: @markrages Using 3 cell li-ion battery(12.6V 2300mAh) to power the circuit

Comment: When you selected an inductor did you account for the fact that the inductance drops off at higher currents - if you look in the datasheets there is usually an I vs L graph, and if you didn't choose wisely you may find the inductance at 0.6A is less than you need.

Comment: Do you have a load on the output? That looks suspiciously like 'burst mode' operation where the output voltage is rising until it exceeds the feedback reference and the switch is shut down until the feedback is back within normal range.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that since it is a switching regulator, it switches OFF completely when the output voltage is more than what it is designed for which is exactly what I don't want. I have shifted my design to MC34166 which is a PWM controlled DC-DC converter and everything seems to be working fine. I am getting an output voltage ripple of 10-15 mV peak to peak @ 5 V o/p and no such 10 Hz ripple.